# Cannot retrieve the URL specified in the Content Link property

Tags: sharepoint-2010, web-parts

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://servername/sites/test/"))
       {
            PageViewerWebPart pvwp = new PageViewerWebPart();
            pvwp.Title = "My Page Viewer Web Part";
            pvwp.ContentLink = "http://www.cnn.com";
        }
```

`Cannot retrieve the URL specified in the Content Link property. For more assistance, contact your site administrator.`

sometimes i get the error `The Web Part has timed out` and sometimes the above error. and i make sure that my internet is working so i opend the browser and able to access the site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not reproduce this, so i would assume it's an permission issue. Try running your code with elevated privileges:

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate
{
    using (var site = new SPSite("http://servername/sites/test/"))
    {
        var pvwp = new PageViewerWebPart
        {
            Title = "My Page Viewer Web Part",
            ContentLink = "http://www.cnn.com"
        };
    }
});
```

Comment: i have all this setup in VM and the only account i have in that box is administrator so when the site is popup i enter my credentials and enter my administrator/password...